# Spring/MongoDB Multi count for unique query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have to translate this query to count all public and private libaries for each category:

```
"$group" : {
  _id:"$category",
  nbPublic:{ $sum: { $cond: { if: "$public", then: 1, else: 0 }}},
  nbPrivate:{ $sum: { $cond: { if: "$public", then: 0, else: 1 }}}
}
```

to get that type of result :

```
{ cat1: { nbPublic: 3, nbPrivate: 5 } },
{ cat2: { nbPublic: 12, nbPrivate: 3 } },
....
```

I tried :

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            group("category").count().as("nbPublic"),
            match(Criteria.where("public").is(true)),
            group("category").count().as("nbPrivate"),
            match(Criteria.where("public").is(false)),
            project("nbPublic").and("category").previousOperation().and("nbPrivate").previousOperation());

    
    AggregationResults<Dest.class> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
            aggregation, Model.class, Dest.class
    );
```

What should I do ?

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `mongoTemplate`

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Then you can do something like this.

```
public List<Object> test(){
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        a-> new Document("$group",
                new Document("_id","$category")
                .append("nbPublic", 
                    new Document("$sum", 
                        new Document ("$cond",
                            new Document("$if", "$public")
                            .append("then",1)
                            .append("else",0)
                        )
                    )
                )
                .append("nbPrivate", 
                    new Document("$sum", 
                        new Document ("$cond",
                            new Document("$if", "$public")
                            .append("then",1)
                            .append("else",0)
                        )
                    )
                )
        )

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

Note : I've not tested. But this should work. this is a kind of [trick](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/) to convert mongo script to spring. Anyhow I'll find and let you know about the Aggregation operations.

**Update 1 : This may be easy way**

```
group("category") 
.sum(ConditionalOperators.when("public").then(1).otherwise(0)).as("nbPublic") 
.sum(ConditionalOperators.when("public").then(0).otherwise(1)).as("nbPrivate")
```

Comment: Thx for you help, but I don't want to translate litteraly the query. Is there any way to succeed using GroupOperation, MatchOperation ... ?

Comment: Can you check this `group("category") .sum(ConditionalOperators.when("public").then(1).otherwise(0)).as("nbPublic") .sum(ConditionalOperators.when("public").then(0).otherwise(1)).as("nbPrivate")`. If that works, i will make this as an answer

Comment: I haven't tested this also